# When I do a scan() in Dynamodb with no filter and retrieve only 10 objects, does it still access the entire database?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

For example (using Boto):

```
import boto

db = boto.connect_dynamodb()

table = db.get_table('MyTable')
res = table.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'], max_results=10)

for i in res:
    print i
```

If I have 1,000 objects in my table, will it scan all of them, or stop after 10? If this does indeed read all 1,000 objects, how can I have it read only the first 10?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation on [capacity unit calculation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations), only up to 1MB of data will be analyzed per single request.

> In case of a scan operation, it is not the size of items returned by scan, rather it is the size of items evaluated by Amazon DynamoDB. That is, for a scan request, Amazon DynamoDB evaluates up to 1 MB of items and returns only the items that satisfy the scan condition.

For tables with 'only' 1,000 items it would theoretically parse all the table each time. Hopefully, the 'limit' parameter (of which maximal value is 100), will allow to stop the process earlier so that at most `limit` items are returned.

If you request does not involve any conditions, the scanned items count will be the number of results. Otherwise, it might be much, much greater but the cumulated size of scanned items can not cross the 1MB boundary.

For scanned operations, Amazon will considered you consumed

```
consumed_capacity = math.ceil(sum(parsed_data_size)/1KB)
```

But please, don't take my word on it:

```
import boto
db = boto.connect_dynamodb()

# Notice the "layer1" operation
res = db.layer1.scan('MyTable', attributes_to_get=['id'], limit=10)

print res['ScannedCount']
```

Comment: The documentation makes it sound like for every scan() operation, the entire table will be scanned but only items less than 1MB or less than the limit will be returned.

Comment: Each ``Scan`` call will trigger the _analysis_ of up to 1MB of items or ``Limit`` Items if reached before. However, you need to call ``Scan`` on the whole table to be sure you did not miss a match in case you are *filtering* the results.

Answer (score 1):

To fully answer your question you need to know also: What is the size of the items in Kb, and what is the provisioned read capacity of your table.

If you scan only items that represent the main index key (in your case 'id') without any filter expression you will receive the first 10 items and the scan will stop.

It won't retrieve the first 10 items if:

1. The size of the items together is bigger than 1MB, in this case you'll need to use more iterations and start the second scan with ExclusiveStartKey = result['LastEvaluatedKey'].

OR

2. If you do not have enough provisioned read capacity so you'll receive a "not enough provisioned throughput exception" and will need to control the scan timing using "limits".